# Algorithm to Group Selected Numbers In a List

Tags: list, algorithm, grouping, modbus, selected

Given a list of consecutive and unique numbers where some are selected and others are not, I need to create groups that contain all selected numbers. The number of groups should be kept to a minimum, and the number of non-required values in the groups should also be kept to a minimum. The max size of the groups is also a variable.

Example list, where * indicates selected number, and group size is limited to 5:
1*,2,3,4,5*,6*,7,8*,9

The most optimized groups would be [(1) and (5,6,7,8)].
[(1,2,3,4,5) and (6,7,8)] is another possible answer, but it contains more non-selected values, thus is not desirable.

Is there a name for this type of algorithm? I don't need someone to write the code for me, just looking for pointers if this problem is already well known.

For those curious what this is for, I am trying to optimize Modbus TCP register requests. A user may define a list of registers they need, and only continuous groups of registers may be requested at a time. Due to TCP latency, we want to make as few requests as possible, and only request the minimum number of non-required registers.

Comment: Seems similar to a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). One thing you need to quantify is the cost of an extra group versus the cost of an extra non-selected value. In your example, the first answer is clearly better because the answers have the same number of groups, but the second answer has more non-selected values. The choice gets harder if for example one answer has 2 groups and 8 non-selected values, and the other answer has 3 groups and 4 non-selected values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,2,4]
groups, current_group = [], []
max_group_size = 4 # here you put your max size
for n in numbers:
    is_valid = is_selected(n)
    if is_valid:
        current_group.append(n)
    elif (not is_valid and current_group) or len(current_group) == max_group_size:
        groups.append(current_group)
        current_group = []
```

Assuming `is_selected` is a function that tells you if a number is selected

Comment: This doesn't check max group size and adds empty groups.

Comment: it can't add empty groups because the only time a group is added is inside of `elif current_group` which is true only when `len(current_group) > 0`. About the max group size you are right, i forgot it, I will edit the answer right now, thanks!